# node gzip unzip file into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip

I am using gzip to zip a json string and then I save it to a file like this:

```
fs.writeFile(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`, JSON.stringify(workspaceTree), (err) => {
    var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
    var inp = fs.createReadStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`);
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`);
    inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
    fs.unlinkSync(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`);
});
```

It seems to work because it creates the file, but I am not sure because I cannot read it back into a variable. This is what I have tried doing:

```
var treeStream = fs.createReadStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`);
zlib.unzip(treeStream, (err, buffer) => {
    if(err){
        connection.console.log((util.inspect(err, false, null)));
    }
    workspaceTree = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
});
```

I am getting the follow error:

> [TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk]

Comment: Since the `fs` operations are asynchronous, it could be the case that the file has not yet finished writing before you attempt to read it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is maybe that you delete the source file before the content has been fully written on disk.

```
fs.writeFile(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`, JSON.stringify(workspaceTree), (err) => {
    var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
    var inp = fs.createReadStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`);
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`);
    inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out).on('close', function () {;
      fs.unlinkSync(`${craneProjectDir}/tree.out`);
    });
});
```

Take care to bind close and not end. close means that the underlying file descriptor is closed, end means the stream has finish to process the data.

When extracting the new file, you have made two mistakes,

- you used zlib.unzip, but the content was **gzipped**, so you must use one of gunzip methods.
- you have used zlib.unzip which expects a **buffer** but you sent it a stream.

To gunzip the content,

```
  var d = '';
  fs.createReadStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`)
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .on('data', function (data){
    d += data.toString()
  })
  .on('end', function (){
    console.log(d);
  })
```

BTW, i suspect you don t need this temp file ;)

Comment: yeah, i figured out you have mixed stream / buffer, gzip / unzip. ill update my answer.

Comment: Actually I figured out that I can just use `fs.readFile` and put the content into a `new Buffer()`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could just use readFile, and put its contents into a Buffer like so:

```
fs.readFile(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`, (err, data) => {
    var treeStream = new Buffer(data);
    zlib.unzip(treeStream, (err, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            connection.console.log((util.inspect(err, false, null)));
        }
        workspaceTree = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
        notifyClientOfWorkComplete();
    });
});
```

Comment: As you used __gzip__, you should use __gunzip__ (zlib.gunzip(buf[, options], callback)). Not sure why it works with zlib.unzip.